# How to update webview?

Tags: android, webview

I need to update my webview because doesnt show anything until i rotate the screen.

My Webview

```
  @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment3, container, false);
    webview = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    String url = "http://www.acr-sl.com/catalogo/1/1/1";
    webview.loadUrl(url);
    return v;
}
```

**UPDATE:**  Finally solved this problem creating the webview from 0 ina new fragment, the only thing it changed were the layouts so the problem was derived from there i suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my Layout file  fragment_meru_detail is as

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<ProgressBar

    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pageload"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Loding........"
        />

<WebView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/meruweb"
    ></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Java Class is as:

```
package com.rayz.digitalpostbox.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.rayz.digitalpostbox.R;
import com.rayz.digitalpostbox.activities.HomeActivity;


public class MeruDetail extends Fragment {

    TextView pageload ;
    WebView webview ;
    private ProgressBar progres;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meru_detail, container, false);
        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).setTitle("MERU Cabs");
         webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.meruweb);
        pageload = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pageload);
        progres = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progres.setMax(100);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://merucabs.com/mobile/");




        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                MeruDetail.this.setValue(progress);
                super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);
                if(progress==100){
                    progres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    progres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                if(progress>40){
                    pageload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

        });

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        MeruDetail.this.progres.setProgress(0);

        return  rootView ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void setValue(int progress) {
        this.progres.setProgress(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).setTitle("Dashboard");
    }
}
```

And I think you should also check in your mainfest file for internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thank you, still working on this, it has to be something stupid because the webview itself works when i change the orientation from vertical to horizontal or viceversa the WebVIew is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for your WebView
webview.reload()

Answer (score 0):

you can `webView.reload()` but be aware this reposts a page if the request was POST, so only works correctly with GET.
If your URL is static or same then you should use loadURL again it's better.

```
YourActivity.this.webView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

below is working code for your requirement have look and implement it as>

Layout file is as:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.webview.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Mainfest file is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lenovo.webview">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java is as:

```
package com.example.lenovo.webview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.acr-sl.com/catalogo/1/1/1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your code but didnt solve the problem, im using fragment maybe is that the problem?

Comment: It is also working in fragment look below i am posting it for fragment